# ieprf vs iperf3 metrics does not match

Tags: performance, bandwidth, iperf

I am not a network expert but I was measuring the network between to physical hosts using iperf and I got different results depending of the version I was using.

Server configuration:

**CPU:**

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                64
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-63
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    8
Socket(s):             4
NUMA node(s):          8
Vendor ID:             AuthenticAMD
CPU family:            21
Model:                 1
Model name:            AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 6282 SE
Stepping:              2
CPU MHz:               2600.166
BogoMIPS:              5199.30
Virtualization:        AMD-V
L1d cache:             16K
L1i cache:             64K
L2 cache:              2048K
L3 cache:              6144K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
NUMA node1 CPU(s):     8-15
NUMA node2 CPU(s):     16-23
NUMA node3 CPU(s):     24-31
NUMA node4 CPU(s):     32-39
NUMA node5 CPU(s):     40-47
NUMA node6 CPU(s):     48-55
NUMA node7 CPU(s):     56-63
```

**NICs:**

x2 ConnectX-4 Lx NICs with XOR bonding and jumbo frames

```
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Mellanox Technologies MT27710 Family [ConnectX-4 Lx]
05:00.1 Ethernet controller: Mellanox Technologies MT27710 Family [ConnectX-4 Lx]

8: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc noqueue state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 7c:fe:90:12:23:ec brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.32.21/16 brd 10.0.255.255 scope global bond0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::b1b0:74dd:8a3:705e/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

DEVICE=bond0
BONDING_OPTS="miimon=110 updelay=0 downdelay=0 mode=balance-xor"
TYPE=Bond
BONDING_MASTER=yes
MTU=9000
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=10.0.32.21
PREFIX=16
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_PRIVACY=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME="Bond connection 1"
UUID=13a75833-cfdd-45f7-b167-6fba85c69c10
ONBOOT=yes
```

Iperf test:

```
[root@hercules-21 ~]# iperf -c 10.0.32.22 -P 4
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 10.0.32.22, TCP port 5001
TCP window size:  325 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  5] local 10.0.32.21 port 50962 connected with 10.0.32.22 port 5001
[  3] local 10.0.32.21 port 50956 connected with 10.0.32.22 port 5001
[  6] local 10.0.32.21 port 50958 connected with 10.0.32.22 port 5001
[  4] local 10.0.32.21 port 50960 connected with 10.0.32.22 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  5]  0.0-10.0 sec  6.92 GBytes  5.94 Gbits/sec
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec  7.00 GBytes  6.01 Gbits/sec
[  6]  0.0-10.0 sec  6.87 GBytes  5.90 Gbits/sec
[  4]  0.0-10.0 sec  6.83 GBytes  5.87 Gbits/sec
[SUM]  0.0-10.0 sec  27.6 GBytes  23.7 Gbits/sec
```

Iperf3 test:

```
[root@hercules-21 ~]# iperf3 -c 10.0.32.22 -P 4
Connecting to host 10.0.32.22, port 5201
[  4] local 10.0.32.21 port 42700 connected to 10.0.32.22 port 5201
[  6] local 10.0.32.21 port 42702 connected to 10.0.32.22 port 5201
[  8] local 10.0.32.21 port 42704 connected to 10.0.32.22 port 5201
[ 10] local 10.0.32.21 port 42706 connected to 10.0.32.22 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr  Cwnd
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec   452 MBytes  3.79 Gbits/sec    0    358 KBytes
[  6]   0.00-1.00   sec   453 MBytes  3.80 Gbits/sec    0    358 KBytes
[  8]   0.00-1.00   sec   453 MBytes  3.80 Gbits/sec    0    350 KBytes
[ 10]   0.00-1.00   sec   453 MBytes  3.80 Gbits/sec    0    384 KBytes
[SUM]   0.00-1.00   sec  1.77 GBytes  15.2 Gbits/sec    0
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec   448 MBytes  3.76 Gbits/sec    0    358 KBytes
[  6]   1.00-2.00   sec   448 MBytes  3.76 Gbits/sec    0    358 KBytes
[  8]   1.00-2.00   sec   448 MBytes  3.76 Gbits/sec    0    350 KBytes
[ 10]   1.00-2.00   sec   448 MBytes  3.76 Gbits/sec    0    384 KBytes
[SUM]   1.00-2.00   sec  1.75 GBytes  15.0 Gbits/sec    0
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec   448 MBytes  3.76 Gbits/sec    0    358 KBytes
[  6]   2.00-3.00   sec   448 MBytes  3.76 Gbits/sec    0    358 KBytes
[  8]   2.00-3.00   sec   448 MBytes  3.76 Gbits/sec    0    350 KBytes
[ 10]   2.00-3.00   sec   448 MBytes  3.76 Gbits/sec    0    384 KBytes
[SUM]   2.00-3.00   sec  1.75 GBytes  15.0 Gbits/sec    0
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec   450 MBytes  3.77 Gbits/sec    0    428 KBytes
[  6]   3.00-4.00   sec   450 MBytes  3.77 Gbits/sec    0    437 KBytes
[  8]   3.00-4.00   sec   451 MBytes  3.78 Gbits/sec    0    516 KBytes
[ 10]   3.00-4.00   sec   452 MBytes  3.79 Gbits/sec    0    603 KBytes
[SUM]   3.00-4.00   sec  1.76 GBytes  15.1 Gbits/sec    0
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec   450 MBytes  3.78 Gbits/sec    0    428 KBytes
[  6]   4.00-5.00   sec   450 MBytes  3.78 Gbits/sec    0    437 KBytes
[  8]   4.00-5.00   sec   450 MBytes  3.78 Gbits/sec    0    516 KBytes
[ 10]   4.00-5.00   sec   451 MBytes  3.78 Gbits/sec    0    603 KBytes
[SUM]   4.00-5.00   sec  1.76 GBytes  15.1 Gbits/sec    0
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec   450 MBytes  3.77 Gbits/sec    0    428 KBytes
[  6]   5.00-6.00   sec   449 MBytes  3.77 Gbits/sec    0    437 KBytes
[  8]   5.00-6.00   sec   450 MBytes  3.77 Gbits/sec    0    516 KBytes
[ 10]   5.00-6.00   sec   450 MBytes  3.77 Gbits/sec    0    603 KBytes
[SUM]   5.00-6.00   sec  1.76 GBytes  15.1 Gbits/sec    0
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec   450 MBytes  3.77 Gbits/sec    0    428 KBytes
[  6]   6.00-7.00   sec   450 MBytes  3.77 Gbits/sec    0    437 KBytes
[  8]   6.00-7.00   sec   450 MBytes  3.77 Gbits/sec    0    516 KBytes
[ 10]   6.00-7.00   sec   450 MBytes  3.77 Gbits/sec    0    603 KBytes
[SUM]   6.00-7.00   sec  1.76 GBytes  15.1 Gbits/sec    0
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec   451 MBytes  3.78 Gbits/sec    0    428 KBytes
[  6]   7.00-8.00   sec   451 MBytes  3.78 Gbits/sec    0    437 KBytes
[  8]   7.00-8.00   sec   450 MBytes  3.78 Gbits/sec    0    516 KBytes
[ 10]   7.00-8.00   sec   451 MBytes  3.78 Gbits/sec    0    603 KBytes
[SUM]   7.00-8.00   sec  1.76 GBytes  15.1 Gbits/sec    0
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec   450 MBytes  3.78 Gbits/sec    0    428 KBytes
[  6]   8.00-9.00   sec   449 MBytes  3.77 Gbits/sec    0    437 KBytes
[  8]   8.00-9.00   sec   450 MBytes  3.78 Gbits/sec    0    516 KBytes
[ 10]   8.00-9.00   sec   449 MBytes  3.77 Gbits/sec    0    603 KBytes
[SUM]   8.00-9.00   sec  1.76 GBytes  15.1 Gbits/sec    0
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec   450 MBytes  3.77 Gbits/sec    0    428 KBytes
[  6]   9.00-10.00  sec   450 MBytes  3.77 Gbits/sec    0    437 KBytes
[  8]   9.00-10.00  sec   450 MBytes  3.77 Gbits/sec    0    516 KBytes
[ 10]   9.00-10.00  sec   451 MBytes  3.78 Gbits/sec    0    603 KBytes
[SUM]   9.00-10.00  sec  1.76 GBytes  15.1 Gbits/sec    0
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  4.39 GBytes  3.77 Gbits/sec    0             sender
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  4.39 GBytes  3.77 Gbits/sec                  receiver
[  6]   0.00-10.00  sec  4.39 GBytes  3.77 Gbits/sec    0             sender
[  6]   0.00-10.00  sec  4.39 GBytes  3.77 Gbits/sec                  receiver
[  8]   0.00-10.00  sec  4.40 GBytes  3.78 Gbits/sec    0             sender
[  8]   0.00-10.00  sec  4.39 GBytes  3.77 Gbits/sec                  receiver
[ 10]   0.00-10.00  sec  4.40 GBytes  3.78 Gbits/sec    0             sender
[ 10]   0.00-10.00  sec  4.39 GBytes  3.77 Gbits/sec                  receiver
[SUM]   0.00-10.00  sec  17.6 GBytes  15.1 Gbits/sec    0             sender
[SUM]   0.00-10.00  sec  17.6 GBytes  15.1 Gbits/sec                  receiver

iperf Done.
[root@hercules-21 ~]#
```

As you can see iperf3 provides a much lower bandwitdh compared to iperf

Adding more parallel requrests didn't help:

```
iperf3 with 24 threads [SUM]   0.00-10.00  sec  13.9 GBytes  11.9 Gbits/sec                  receiver
iperf3 8 threads [SUM]   0.00-10.00  sec  16.3 GBytes  14.0 Gbits/sec                  receiver
```

**QUESTION:**

Why am I getting such a difference between iperf and iperf3?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Iperf3 is not multi-threaded (as iperf2 is).

You need to start multiple iperf3 servers/clients to achieve the same (not using -P).

More info can be found here:

https://fasterdata.es.net/performance-testing/network-troubleshooting-tools/iperf/multi-stream-iperf3/

Hope it helps!